# R grep to match dot

Tags: regex, r

So I have two strings like `mylist<-c('claim', 'cl.bi')`, when I do

```
grep('^cl\\.*', mylist)
```

it returns both 1 and 2. But if I do

```
grep('^cl\\.', mylist)
```

it will only return 2. So why would the first match `'claim'`? What happened to the period matching?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`"^cl\\.*"` matches `"claim"` because the `*` quantifier is defined thusly (here quoting from ?regex):

```
'*' The preceding item will be matched zero or more times.
```

`"claim"` contains a beginning of line, followed by a `c`,  followed by an `l`, followed by zero (in this case) or more dots, so fulfilling all the requirements for a successful match.

If you want to only match strings beginning `cl.`, use the *one or more times* quantifier, `+`, like this:

```
grep('^cl\\.+', mylist, value=TRUE)
# [1] "cl.bi"
```

Answer (score 2):

The **`*`** operator tells the engine to match it's preceding token "zero or more" times. In the first case, the engine trys matching a *literal* dot  "zero or more" times  — which might be none at all.

Essentially, if you use the `*` operator, it will still match if there are no instances of (`.`)

A better visualization:

```
*      --→   equivalent to {0,}      --→   match preceding token (0 or more times)
\\.*   --→   equivalent to \\.{0,}   --→   match ., .., ..., etc or an empty match
                                                                       ↑↑↑↑↑
```

Comment: I'm just impressed by those little arrows you made

Answer (score 1):

The quantifier `*` means *zero or more times*. Pay attention to the *zero*. It applies to the preceding token, which is `\.` in your case.

In short, the `cl` part matches, and the dot after it isn't required.

Here are the matched substrings for both cases:

```
claim
--

cl.bi
---
```

Answer (score 1):

To simplify what the others have said: `'^cl\\.*'` is just equivalent to `'^cl'`, since the `*` matches 0+ occurrences of the `\\.`

Whereas `'^cl\\.'` forces it to match an actual dot. It is equivalent to `'^cl\\.{1}'`