# Removing characters in column titles after "."

Tags: r

I have a question similar to the one asked here: [r Remove parts of column name after certain characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37800704/r-remove-parts-of-column-name-after-certain-characters) however I have a slight wrinkle. My column titles have formats sich as ENSG00000124564.16 and ENSG00000257509.1, however I want to remove all characters after the `.`

I cannot just remove the last x characters, as the column titles vary in the number of characters after the `.` symbol

If I follow the `sub()` command in the previous question, like here: `sub(".*", "", colnames(dataset[6:ncol(dataset)]))`, it does nothing. I assume because in the normal command the `.` symbol is used to seperate the string you are searching for and the `*` symbol to represent anything after it.

How do I alter the code to use `.` as the string search symbol? This is probably a very simple question.

Comment: `.` in regex is a special character that means any character. If you want to match it literally, you can escape it with `\\.` or `[.]`, or set `fixed = TRUE` to not use regex

Comment: Does this answer your question? [R grep to match dot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32916884/r-grep-to-match-dot)

Comment: Also I think you're misunderstanding the regex you're using: `*` matches zero or more occurrences of a character/pattern. So `"a*"` would match "abc", "aaa", and "xyz", because you're not requiring that `"a"` actually be there in order to match. Maybe you're confusing regex with globbing?

Comment: Thanks, I had tried to use `[]` to seperate out the `.` symbol, but it still wouldn't work. I was comitted to modifying the column titles directly before, as I outlined in my response to sm925 below, but it wouldn't work. I managed to get it working by creating a list of my column names first, then modifying them using `sub()` or `gsub()`, and then replacing the column titles with the modified list. I still don't understand why it wouldn't work directly.

Comment: Maybe if you included your code & data (see [reproducible example guidance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)) it would be more clear what isn't working—I'm not sure what you mean by modifying directly. Calling `names` returns a vector; to change those names you need to assign a vector back to `names`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can escape period like this `\\.`:

```
x <- "ENSG00000124564.16"
sub("\\..*", "", x)
#[1] "ENSG00000124564"
```

## update:

```
## if you have list of strings it works
x <- c("ENSG00000124564.16",  "ENSG00000257509.1")
sub("\\..*", "", x)
# [1] "ENSG00000124564" "ENSG00000257509"

## if you want to try it to change the column names it works
df <- data.frame(ENSG00000124564.16 = c(1, 2, 3), ENSG00000257509.1 = c(1, 1, 1))
names(df) <- sub("\\..*", "", names(df))
#  ENSG00000124564 ENSG00000257509
#1               1               1
#2               2               1
#3               3               1
```

Comment: This worked when I tried it on a single string `x <- "ENSG00000124564.16"`, and when I tried it on a list of strings`x <- colnames(dataset)`, but it wouldn't work when I tried to change the column names directly `colnames(dataset) <- gsub("\\..*$", "", colnames(dataset))`

The problem is fixed now, as I could just use the list of strings to replace my column names, but still unsure why it wouldn't work directly.

Comment: @PhilD I have updated answer. It's working for me. You can add reproducible example of your sample data set for me to figure out why it's not working in that case.

Answer (score 3):

with `\\.` you indicate a dot. With `.` you indicate any kind of character. With `.*` you indicate any kind of character any number of times. With `$` you indicate that it is the end of the string. So you can put those together as such:

```
df <- data.frame(ENSG00000124564.16=c(1,2,3), ENSG00000257509.1=c(4,5,6))
df

colnames(df) <- gsub("\\..*$", "", colnames(df))
df
```

edit: sm925 was too fast for my slow typing :)